# Image autoslider for dynamic folder's content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'd like to make autoslide gallery.I wonder how to start it... It got to be dynamic, because folder content will change with time. Typing  is not what I'm looking for. Can You give me any advices or tutorials I can base on? I was searching but there's no for dynamic folder content...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very generic example and may not be direct copy/paste for you but it should help you learn the fundamentals of achieving your intended result.

Using this library:
https://gist.github.com/tsohil/623538

Assuming you want to get all of the images in the folder.

First, we'll use PHP to fetch the file names doing so along the lines of:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(glob("folder/relative/to/controller/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE));
```

Our HTML we will stage as:

```
<div id="carousel"></div>
```

Then in our JS (example requires jQuery) we will send a request for to that.

```
$.get('/phpcontroller.php', {}, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(val) => {
        $("#carousel").append("<div class=\"inactive\">
           <img width=\"946\" height=\"473\" src=\"/path/to/folder/"+val+"\" class=\"car-img\">
        </div>");
    });
});
```